# Buttons are not being shown with icons in apache cordova using jquery mobile and nativedroid2. How do I show them?

Tags: css, cordova, jquery-mobile, nativedroid

I am new to apache cordova and I am making a data collection app using jquery mobile and nativedroid2. The code I am using is this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nativedroid2.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/waves.min.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">

        <title>Sales | DocNme</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <!--  <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        --> 

        <div data-role = "page" id = "page-1">
                <div data-role = "header">
                </div>
                <div data-role = "main" class = "ui-content">
                </div>
                 <div data-role = "footer" data-position="fixed" style="border:none;">
                    <div align="center" style = "position:relative;"><img src="img/load.GIF" height="50" width="50"></div>
                    <p align="center" style="position:relative;">Loading...</p>
                 </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role = "page" id = "page-2">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <!--<img class="logo" src="img/logoTagline.png"/>-->
                <span class="logo"></span>
            </div>
                <div role="main" class="ui-content wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
                    <h3>Sign In</h3>
                    <div id="signin-error-msg" class="ui-bg clr-bg-red">
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-alert-triangle"></i> <span id="signin-error-msg-text"></span>
                    </div>
                    <label for="signin-username">User Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="signin-username" id="signin-username" value="" placeholder="user@domain.com" />
                    <label for="signin-password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="signin-password" id="signin-password" value="" placeholder="Enter your password here..." />
                    <div class="row center-xs">
                        <div class="col-xs">
                            <div class="box">
                                   <a href="#page-3" class="ui-btn ui-btn-raised">Sing In</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  

                     <a  href="#page-4" class="ui-btn
                            ui-btn-inline
                            ui-btn-fab
                            ui-btn-fab-bottom
                            ui-btn-raised
                            clr-primary waves-effect waves-button waves-effect waves-button"></a>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role = "page" id = "page-3" class="nd2-no-menu-swipe">

            <div data-role = "header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" style="background-color:rgb(60,190,205)">

                    <!-- <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6" data-name="arrow-back">
                        <div class="box"> -->
                            <a href="#page-2" class="ui-btn ui-btn-left"><i class="zmdi zmdi-refresh"></i></a>
                       <!--  </div>
                    </div>
 -->
                    <ul data-role="nd2tabs" data-swipe="false">

                        <li data-tab="friends">Friends</li>
                        <li data-tab="work" data-tab-active="true">Work</li>

                    </ul>

            </div>

             <div data-role="main" class="ui-content wow fadeIn" data-inset="false" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                  
                    <div data-role="nd2tab" data-tab="friends">

                    <!-- <nd2-ad data-banner="sample.banner"></nd2-ad> -->

                                            <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false">
                                                <li data-role="list-divider">
                                                    Friends
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#">
                                                        <img src="img/smile.png" class="ui-thumbnail ui-thumbnail-circular" />
                                                        <h2>Ethel Chancy</h2>
                                                        <p>ehtel.chancy@example.com</p>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#">
                                                        <img src="img/smile.png" class="ui-thumbnail ui-thumbnail-circular" />
                                                        <h2>Lorean Gainer</h2>
                                                        <p>lorean87@mail.com</p>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#">
                                                        <img src="img/smile.png" class="ui-thumbnail ui-thumbnail-circular" />
                                                        <h2>Juliet Gieseke</h2>
                                                        <p>flowerpower69@rainbow.com</p>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>


                    </div>


                    <div data-role="nd2tab" data-tab="work">

                    <!-- <nd2-ad data-banner="sample.banner"></nd2-ad> -->

                                            <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false">
                                                <li data-role="list-divider">
                                                   Work
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#">
                                                        <img src="img/smile.png"/>
                                                        <h2>Ethel Chancy</h2>
                                                        <p>ehtel.chancy@example.com</p>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#">
                                                        <img src="img/smile.png"/>
                                                        <h2>Lorean Gainer</h2>
                                                        <p>lorean87@mail.com</p>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#">
                                                        <img src="img/smile.png"/>
                                                        <h2>Juliet Gieseke</h2>
                                                        <p>flowerpower69@rainbow.com</p>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>

                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role = "page" id = "page-4">
                page 4
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/waves.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/wow.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/nativedroid2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

In the code above, the icon I am trying to show in the header section of the `div` with `id = "page-3"` does not show up on the screen. Please help me out. Thanks in advance. [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDeOz.png) would have shown the refresh icon inside the red circle that I have highlighted, but nothing is there

Comment: try after adding `data-role="button" role="button"` in that anchor tag.

Comment: No change. ;( The surprising thing is that if I click on the area it navigates to the other page, but the icon is invisible, still.

Comment: that means `css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css` is not loaded.
just add it into your project and you should be good to go. @horcrux

Comment: it is still not up to the mark. But now it shows a rectangle in place of the refresh icon. Could there be any clash between the css files I am linking to the document @ArpitVasani

Comment: yes that could be the problem. can you host your code on jsFiddle or on other public server so that I can debug exactly.

Comment: I pposted the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/akkisinghpanchaal/99hh5g7j/)

Comment: you need to add css and js in order to run that code in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Add this reference at the end of your CSS includes.

```
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css"
```